# Unable to remote debug asp.net mvc core application on IIS8 (AWS EC2)

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, remote-debugging, dnx

I have an MVC core website written in C# which is deployed to an AWS EC2 Instance with Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS8 deployed on it.

I am trying to remote debug the application as I am getting errors thrown which I don't when running locally (details for another post maybe).

On AWS Console, I have a security group with the following Rules as guided by [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592018.aspx):
[image: Inbound rules]
[image: Outbound Rules]

and when I click on `Debug->Attach to process`, and browse to my AWS instance, I can see the correct dnx.exe process, however, when I attach to that process,

[image]

I get the `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document`

I've tried going to `Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols` and clicking `Load all symbols` as it is my understanding that since VS2012 the symbols do not need to be deployed, but rather just on the local machine doing the debugging, taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx).

> In versions of Visual Studio before VS 2012, debugging managed code on a remote device required that the symbol files were also located on the remote machine. This is no longer the case. All symbol files must be located on the local machine or in a location specified in the Debugging / Symbols page of the Visual Studio Options dialog box. See .NET Remote Symbol Loading Changes in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 on the Microsoft Application Lifecycle blog.

I can see the connections being initiated in the MSVSMON process on the EC2 instance.

I feel like I'm close but I'm just missing one simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on which port the Remote Debugger is running and allow inbound traffic on that port by opening **Inbound Port [4024 in my case] with a Custom TCP Rule** for Remote Debugging.

You can check the port used by Remote Debugger at **Tools > Options** in the Remote Debugger Menu.